# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context

Tags: nestjs

I try to run NestJs test but got the following error

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.`

This project is using Mongoose for connecting to MongoDB

You can reproduce the error by running code in this repo
https://github.com/kruyvanna/nestjs-test-error

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll get that error because you have the following module:

```js
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [CatService],
}).compile();
```

and this provider:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CatService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Cat.name) private catModel: Model<CatDocument>) {}
}
```

and there is no way to tell what's the value of `catModel` as its provider token was not registered within the testing module.

To fix that you could register it [like the docs show](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#testing)

```js
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [CatService, { provide: getModelToken(Cat.name), useValue: jest.fn() }],
}).compile();
```